# Execute ant target before build artifact in IntelliJ 12?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an ant target that creates a class with constant holding the current subversion revision number.

With the `Execute on / Before Compilation` setting the revision number will always be up-to-date. BUT! When you're in development mode and compile and run often you don't want that annoying delay when the ant target is being run. Also, there is that Ant messages window popping up. No good.

Obviously I only want to run the ant target before I build for production, when I build the WAR file. In the `Project Settings / Artifacts` there is a Pre-processing tab that makes it possible to run an ant target before the artifact is built. However, the target is run only after the compilation is complete.

Is there a way to make IntelliJ 12 execute an Ant target before the compilation and creation of a WAR file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dummy Run configuration that will run something unrelated, but in the **Before launch** put something like:

1. Run Ant Target
2. Make
3. Build Artifact

Now you can use this configuration for the production build.